# Error en c++ no identificado

Tags: c++

AYUDA POR FAVOR!! es c++
mi código estaba bien hasta el día de ayer y hoy quise agregar unas cosas y me puse editarlo pero ahora no me deja hacer nada, no deja de ejecutarse y no me deja elegir opción ni ingresar nada (lo peor es que no me salta error y por mas que busco no se que paso)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define BLOQUE 5

struct Pelicula{
string nameP;
string genero;
string actor;
int edad;
string papel;
};

 struct ListaDinamica{
 int total;
int max;
Pelicula *datos;
};

 void llenar(Pelicula &P){
cout << "Ingrese nombre de la pelicula: ";
cin >> P.nameP;
cout << "Ingrese genero de pelicula: ";
cin >> P.genero;
cout << "Ingrese nombre del actor o actriz: ";
cin >> P.actor;
cout << "Ingrese edad: ";
cin >> P.edad;
cout << "Ingrese papel protagonico: ";
cin >> P.papel;

}

 void mostrar(Pelicula *P){
cout << "  Datos de Actor  " << endl;
cout << "Nombre: " << endl;
cout << "Edad: " << endl;
cout << "Papel protagonico: " << endl;

}

 void inicializar(ListaDinamica &LD){
LD.total = 0;
LD.max = 0;
LD.datos = NULL;
}

void crece(ListaDinamica &LD){
Pelicula *aux = new Pelicula[LD.max + BLOQUE];
for (int i = 0; i < LD.max; ++i) {
    *(aux + i) = *(LD.datos+i);
}
delete []LD.datos;
LD.datos;
LD.max = LD.max + BLOQUE;
}

void agregar(ListaDinamica &LD, Pelicula P){
if (LD.total==LD.max){
    crece(LD);
}
*(LD.datos+ LD.total) = P;
LD.total++;
}

void presentar (ListaDinamica LD){
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
   mostrar(LD.datos+i);
}
}

int opciones(){
int op;
cout << "1. Agregar Pelicula" <<endl;
cout << "2. Presentar lista de peliculas: " <<endl;
cout << "3. Buscar pelicula por nombre: " << endl;
cout << "4. Buscar pelicula por genero: " << endl;
cout << "5. Buscar actor por nombre" <<endl;
cout << "6. Buscar actor por edad" <<endl;
cout << "7. Buscar actor por papel protagonico" <<endl;
cout << "8. SALIR" <<endl;
cout << "***ELEGIR OPCION: ***" <<endl;
 }

void op_agregarPelicula(ListaDinamica &LD){
Pelicula P;
llenar (P);
agregar(LD, P);
}
void op_buscar(ListaDinamica LD){
string namePAux;
bool encuentra = false;
cout << "Ingresa nombre de pelicula a buscar: ";
cin >> namePAux;
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
        if ((LD.datos + i)->nameP==namePAux){
        cout << "*Pelicula encontrada*" <<endl;
        mostrar(LD.datos+ i);
        encuentra = true;
        break;
        }
}
if(encuentra == false){
    cout <<  "**Esta pelicula no existe**" << endl;
}
}
void op_actor(ListaDinamica LD){
string actorAux;
bool encontrado =false;
cout <<"Ingrese nombre de actor a encontrar: ";
cin >>actorAux;
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
    if ((LD.datos + i)->papel == actorAux) {
        mostrar(LD.datos+ i);
        encontrado = true;
    }
}
if (encontrado == false) {
   cout << "*Nombre  de actor no encontrado**"<< endl;
}
 }

void op_actor_papel(ListaDinamica LD){
string papelAux;
bool encontrado =false;
cout <<"Ingrese papel de actor a encontrar: ";
cin >>papelAux;
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
    if ((LD.datos + i)->papel == papelAux) {
        mostrar(LD.datos+ i);
        encontrado = true;
    }
}
if (encontrado == false) {
   cout << "**Papel protagonico no encontrado**"<< endl;
}
}
void op_edad(ListaDinamica LD){
int edadAux;
bool encontrado =false;
cout <<"Ingrese edad de actor a encontrar: ";
cin >>edadAux;
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
    if ((LD.datos + i)->edad == edadAux) {
        mostrar(LD.datos+ i);
        encontrado = true;
    }
}
if (encontrado == false) {
   cout << "*Edad de actor no encontrada**"<< endl;
}
 }
 void op_genero(ListaDinamica LD){
string generoAux;
bool encontrado =false;
cout <<"Ingrese  genero de pelicula a encontrar: ";
cin >>generoAux;
for (int i = 0; i < LD.total; ++i) {
    if ((LD.datos + i)->genero == generoAux) {
        mostrar(LD.datos+ i);
        encontrado = true;
    }
}
if (encontrado == false) {
   cout << "**Genero de pelicula no encontrada**"<< endl;
}
}

int main()
{

ListaDinamica LD;
int op;

inicializar(LD);
do{
   op = opciones();
   switch (op) {
   case 1:op_agregarPelicula(LD);
       break;
   case 2: presentar(LD);
       break;
   case 3: op_buscar(LD);
       break;
   case 4: op_genero(LD);
       break;
   case 5: op_actor(LD);
       break;
   case 6: op_edad(LD);
      break;
   case 7: op_actor_papel(LD);
       break;
   default:
       cout << "ERROR en opcion" << endl;
       break;
   }
}while(op != 8);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu fallo esta en la función `int opciones()`

```
int opciones(){
    int op;
    cout << "1. Agregar Pelicula" <<endl;
    cout << "2. Presentar lista de peliculas: " <<endl;
    cout << "3. Buscar pelicula por nombre: " << endl;
    cout << "4. Buscar pelicula por genero: " << endl;
    cout << "5. Buscar actor por nombre" <<endl;
    cout << "6. Buscar actor por edad" <<endl;
    cout << "7. Buscar actor por papel protagonico" <<endl;
    cout << "8. SALIR" <<endl;
    cout << "***ELEGIR OPCION: ***" <<endl;
}
```

Te falta hacer un `cin >>` a tu variable `op`, y después retornarla para utilizarla en el `switch` que tienes en el `main()`

Tu función quedaría así:

```
int opciones(){
    int op;
    cout << "1. Agregar Pelicula" <<endl;
    cout << "2. Presentar lista de peliculas: " <<endl;
    cout << "3. Buscar pelicula por nombre: " << endl;
    cout << "4. Buscar pelicula por genero: " << endl;
    cout << "5. Buscar actor por nombre" <<endl;
    cout << "6. Buscar actor por edad" <<endl;
    cout << "7. Buscar actor por papel protagonico" <<endl;
    cout << "8. SALIR" <<endl;
    cout << "***ELEGIR OPCION: ***" <<endl;

    cin >> op;
    return op;
 }
```

Comment: joder no puedo creerlo jajajaa, gracias :))))

Comment: @WillySalazar Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, la forma de dar las gracias es **aceptándola** (el símbolo ✔ a la izquierda de la respuesta, justo debajo de la puntuación). Y, cuando tengas suficiente reputación, lo adecuado es votar positivo a las respuestas que consideres correctas. ¿ Has pasado por [la ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y realizado [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ? Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya servido, como te indica mi compañero @Trauma, marca el check para dejar la respuesta como aceptada.